# in which case one would use uncompress codec for parquet files in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, snappy

I'm new in Spark and trying to understand how different compression codecs work. I'm using Cloudera Quickstart VM 5.12x, Spark 1.6.0 and Python APIs.

If I compress and save as Parquet files using below logic:

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec","snappy")
df.write.parquet("/user/cloudera/data/orders_parquet_snappy")
```

then I can read them as:

```
sqlContext.read.parquet("/user/cloudera/data/orders_parquet_snappy").show()
```

I believe above read doesn't need to uncompress and read. I wonder why and in which condition I will use uncompressed ?

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "uncompressed")
```

Not sure if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Compression is good because it saves at-rest storage and transfer bandwidth (both in terms of local disk I/O and network), but it does so at the cost of computing power. These are the metrics that you want to keep in mind when selecting a compression algorithm for your data: depending on the kind of expectation that you have, you can decide to select the appropriate one.

But in general, Snappy has been specifically designed to be relatively easy on CPU while providing a fair storage/bandwidth saving, which makes it more than appropriate for many use cases (which is why it's the default).

The sensible suggestion is of course to measure and come to a decision based on your observations on your particular setup, but I believe it's fair to say you should not expect a massive relative improvement on resource usage (but probably enough to be of some economic relevance if you are working with a truly massive cluster).

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to use "uncompressed" before reading compressed file ?

Comment: No, the compression algorithm should be picked automatically and you should only specify it when writing.